# Trying to create custom functions in Python with numpy

Tags: python, function, numpy

I'm trying to create a custom function that outputs details of my data frame.
I run the following code on my jupyter notebook, but it just runs without any output displayed.

```
def details(mydf,n):
    mydf.shape
    mydf.dtypes
    mydf.head(n)
    mydf.tail(n)
    return None
```

```
mydf=pd.read_csv("House.Price.csv",low_memory=False)
details(mydf,5)
```

Comment: Are you not forgetting to print? `...print(mydf.shape)` for example

Comment: Your function returns `None`; you are not printing anything. It is not clear what you expect to happen.

Comment: @wwii guneetgstar gave me the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display data in `jupyter` use function `display(<arg>)` like this:

```
def details(mydf,n):
   display(mydf.shape)
   display(mydf.dtypes)
   display(mydf.head(n))
   display(mydf.tail(n))
```

**EDIT**

`display()` function is also configurable about how many rows or column you want to output.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None) // for all
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
```

What you are doing is calling a function that returns `None` and hence no output as by default `jupyter` only prints the value returned by the last line of the block.

Comment: print would also work fine but its not recommended.

Comment: Thank You. Exactly what I needed

Comment: Welcome, you can accept the answer and close it if it resolved your issue.